# API to get guests expiration date in Slack

Tags: slack

Slack displays the expiration date for guests in the profile view (if set). But which API is used for that?

I only found an API to change the value https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.setExpiration

[image]

Comment: I found slack.com/api/users.admin.fetchTeamUsers with a field named "guest_expiration_ts" but it is undocumented and there are no hits on google :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even it is undocumented, https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info provides `guest_expiration_ts` as part of the `profile` element (I tried it with a bot token on a restricted user (multichannel guest))

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using SCIM APIs to fetch the required result.

You'll fin dthe documentation here:
https://api.slack.com/scim#scim-api-endpoints__schemas